# Selenium webdriver: Can not click on a button in a pop up window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

On a website i am trying to click on a button called Agree and Proceed to accept the cookies which is shown in a pop-up but it doesn't click...

This is the html:

```
'<div>'
 '<div class="mainContent" aria-hidden="false" style="">'
    '<div class="pdynamicbutton">'
       '<a class="call" tabindex="1" role="button">Agree and Proceed</a>'
```

My code in eclipse:

```
'@When("^I click on agree terms and conditions$")
    public void i_click_on_agree_terms_and_conditions() throws Throwable {'

'driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='call']/span[text()='Agree And 
Proceed']")).click();'`
```

I have also built in some wait for page to load (30 sec).

Comment: I see no span children. Try `//a[@class='call' and text()='Agree And 
Proceed']`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn’t work. I am trying to click on agree and proceed when going to the www.kruidvat.nl URL

Comment: What if to replace `"And"` with `"and"` in `text()='Agree And Proceed'`?

Comment: @Sven152 are you sure "Agree and Proceed" message shown every time? I didn't get any messages about cookies in www.kruidvat.nl

Comment: Yes. Try incognito mode in your browser. ‘and’ is also not working..

Comment: @Sven152 this might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48771902/7877196

Comment: @Sven152, The locator you are using is not correct because I don't see span child node in the above `HTML`. I did not find the `Agree and Proceed` button in the above-mentioned URL, Please prove some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try
//div[@class='mainContent']//a[contains(text(),'Agree and Proceed')]

Comment: The following message appears:
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: 
Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression 
        '//div[@class='mainContent']//a[contains(text(),'Agree And Proceed'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 
     '//div[@class='mainContent']//a[contains(text(),'Agree And Proceed']' is not a valid XPath expression.'
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Comment: Did you put the path within double quote? It is giving SyntaxError.Try modifing the XPath little bit

Comment: Could it be that the element doesn’t click because of another language setting on my laptop?